# Recover bold text in cell using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

I'm trying to check if the text in cell (Excel file) is bold or not.
For now I'm using :

```
final CellStyle cellStyle = row.getCell(cellIndex).getCellStyle().toString();
```

This doesn't give any information about bold text or not. But I've seen that getCellStyle() possesses several methods like "getFontIndex()". Does it exist one to know if the text is bold or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit convoluted, but it is the `Font` that contains the Bold Attribute, not the `CellStyle`. You can retrieve it from the `CellStyle` in a roundabout way though.

```
Workbook book = row.getSheet().getWorkbook();
CellStyle style = row.getCell(cellIndex).getCellStyle();
int fontIndex = style.getFontIndex();
Font font = book.getFontAt(fontIndex);
if (font.getBold()) {
    // if you are here, the font is bold
}
```

This will tell you if the `CellStyle` contains a bold font. The text in the cell can be a `RichTextString` though, and it can be a totally different font than what is specified in the `CellStyle`. The `RichTextString` support is not complete though, so you will have to do some casting to retrieve the font from that if necessary.